# How can you convert a VUE output to String format in PHP

Tags: php, sql, qr-code

I have this QR code system. It displays the scanned QR code well on the PHP page but it inserts {{ scan.content }} into the database. I wanted the scanned code to be inserted instead. Is there a function that converts it. Thanks!

```
<section class="scans"> 
<h2>Scans</h2> 
<ul v-if="scans.length === 0"> 
<li class="empty">No scans yet</li> </ul> 
<transition-group name="scans" tag="ul"> 
<li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">

<?php $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'crud') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); $client = "{{ scan.content }}"; 

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO masterlist (FirstN) VALUES('$client')") or die($mysqli->error); echo $client; ?> 

</li> 
</transition-group> </section>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: <section class="scans">
        <h2>Scans</h2>
        <ul v-if="scans.length === 0">
          <li class="empty">No scans yet</li>
        </ul>
        <transition-group name="scans" tag="ul">
          <li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">

Comment: <?php
            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'crud') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            $client = "{{ scan.content }}";
       
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO masterlist (FirstN)  VALUES('$client')")
              or die($mysqli->error);
            
          echo $client;
         

            
           ?>


          </li>
   

 

  
 

        </transition-group>
      </section>

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the code. Code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: `{{ }}` is Vue and Blade syntax, not PHP syntax. Considering it's inside straight PHP syntax, PHP is treating it as a full string.

Comment: Since it started in VUE. Is it possible to insert the result of VUE / Scanned QR result to MySQL database. Can you provide a sample syntax.

Comment: You need to use ajax/axios requests to a PHP file to import the data into the database. Remember that PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, javascript/Vue after.